# Conditionally keep duplicates based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
(Pdb++) df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': '2019-01-01', 'type': 'Q'},{'date': '2019-01-01', 'type': 'Y'},{'date': '2019-01-01', 'type': 'H'},{'date': '2019-01-02', 'type': 'Q'},{'date': '2019-01-02', 'type': 'Y'},{'date': '2019-01-03', 'type': 'H'},{'date': '2019-01-04', 'type': 'H'},{'date': '2019-01-04', 'type': 'Q'}]).set_index('date')
(Pdb++) df
           type
date           
2019-01-01    Q
2019-01-01    Y
2019-01-01    H
2019-01-02    Q
2019-01-02    Y
2019-01-03    H
2019-01-04    H
2019-01-04    Q
```

I want to delete duplicated dates in the index based on the duplicated rows' values in the `type` column.

### Requirements

- If a duplicated date contains `Q`, `Y` and `H`, delete the `H`.
- If a duplicated date contains `Q` and `Y`, delete nothing.
- If a duplicated date contains `Q` and `H`, delete the `H`.

A simpler way of putting this is: **In a group of duplicated rows, delete the `H`, if any.**

### Expected output

With this, the expected output of the above would be as follows: `(2019-01-01, H)` and `(2019-01-04, H)` removed

```
           type
date           
2019-01-01    Q
2019-01-01    Y
2019-01-02    Q
2019-01-02    Y
2019-01-03    H
2019-01-04    Q
```

### Attempts

I can't seem to get this quite right. My two attempts:

```
df.loc[(df['type'] == 'Y') | (df['type'] == 'Q') | ~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]

df.loc[(df['type'] == 'Y') | (df['type'] == 'Q') | ~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

The first one fails to delete `(2019-01-01, H)` and the second one fails to delete `(2019-01-04, H)`.

I thought about sorting the `type` column first to get the `H` values first and then use `keep='first'`, but that for some inexplicable reason gives me an error:

```
(Pdb++) df.sort_values('type').loc[(df['type'] == 'Y') | (df['type'] == 'Q') | ~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
*** ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I'm lost here. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group the index to and take nunique, then filter the condition where size is greater than 1, also check if `type` is `H` and negate them:

```
s=df.groupby(df.index)['type'].transform('nunique')
df[~((s>1)&df.type.eq('H'))]
```

---

```
           type
date           
2019-01-01    Q
2019-01-01    Y
2019-01-02    Q
2019-01-02    Y
2019-01-03    H
2019-01-04    Q
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter out of all `H` values, if not groups with only values `H`:

```
m = df.type.eq('H')
df = df[~m | m.groupby(level=0).transform('all')]
print (df)
           type
date           
2019-01-01    Q
2019-01-01    Y
2019-01-02    Q
2019-01-02    Y
2019-01-03    H
2019-01-04    Q
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m.groupby(level=0).transform('all'))
date
2019-01-01    False
2019-01-01    False
2019-01-01    False
2019-01-02    False
2019-01-02    False
2019-01-03     True
2019-01-04    False
2019-01-04    False
Name: type, dtype: bool
```